# Zip/Postal Code Validation on Lead Object

Tags: validation, leads, address

I would like to create validation on the lead object that ensures a user must enter the Zip/PostalCode in the correct sequence of characters. The Zip/PostalCode must always end with a space and three letters (Eg. ‘ 3DG’). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to use a Validation Rule. It supports Regular Expressions and therefore you find a REGEX() formula function:

- https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm (scroll down a lot...)
- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008vYrIAI

Also have a look at this examples:

- https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_useful_validation_formulas_contact.htm&language=en_US